# How to read a filename and write a specific value from it depending on what is in an xml file?

Tags: vb.net

Good Afternoon,

I'm new to VB.net and am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for my VB.Net windows form project.

I need some help with my code as I am unsure on how to do what I want to do.

The scenario is this:

The user selects a directory on the form and pushes a button. The application will then look for some files and move them to another directory. In that new directory it will find file names with a three character code in them.

The application will then assign the appropriate docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values for each code from the xml file. And then output this to a text file.

Having the application know what docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values from the xml file to use depending on the files filename is where I am at a lost on how to do.

My xml file structure is below. Please note that these values are NOT static and can be changed by the user at any time within my settings form.

```
<Settings>
 <ApplicationSettings>
   <code>FTO</code>
   <docgroup>Operations</docgroup>
   <doctype>Funds Transfer</doctype>
   <docsubtype>Out</docsubtype>
   <code>FTI</code>
   <docgroup>null</docgroup>
   <doctype>null</doctype>
   <docsubtype>null</docsubtype>
   <code>ACL</code>
   <docgroup>Documentation</docgroup>
   <doctype>Client Documentation</doctype>
   <docsubtype>Termination</docsubtype>
   <code>TBA</code>
   <docgroup>Operations</docgroup>
   <doctype>Funds Transfer Credit</doctype>
   <docsubtype>Reversed</docsubtype>
 </ApplicationSettings>
</Settings>
```

So for example:

User selects the \ServerA\ITDept\files directory, all the files within this directory will always have the naming convention of:

AccNum-YYYYMMDD-code Example: 123456-20130610-FTO

\ServerA\ITDept\files

12345-20130610-FTO Reviewed and scanned.pdf

54265-20130512-FTI A1.pdf

45752-20121204-TBA.pdf

So if I can figure out how to write this code the output of these files to the text file will look like below:

```
\\ServerA\ITDept\files\12345-20130610-FTO Reviewed and scanned.pdf|12345|_||Operations| Funds Transfer|Out|swfoi6848484|06/10/2013| 
\\ServerA\ITDept\files\54265-20130512-FTI A1.pdf|54265|_||NULL| NULL|NULL|swfoi15157|05/12/2013| 
\\ServerA\ITDept\files\45752-20121204-TBA.pdf|45752|_||Operations|Funds Transfer|Reversed|swfoi54572258|12/04/2012|
```

There will be other files in the directory with other codes, these should just be ignored if these codes are not present in the xml file.

My code is below. EVERYTHING WORKS "except" for this last step of incorporating the specific docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values from the xml file in to the output file.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Userform

Dim xmlfile As String = "\\ServerA\ITDept\XML\Settings.xml"


Private Sub Userform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Check if Setting.xml exists, if not show message box and close application.
    If IO.File.Exists(xmlfile) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate Settings.xml file. Please contact IT Department for assistance.", "ERROR")
        Me.Close()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub filebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles filebtn.Click

    'New thread will run main tasks of program
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

'Function used to get date in file name and use value as MM/DD/YYYY in output file

Private Function GetFormattedDateFromFileName(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim parts() As String = fileName.Split("-")
    If parts.Length = 3 Then
        Dim dt As DateTime
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(parts(1), "yyyyMMdd", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
            Return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        End If
    End If
    Return ""
End Function

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    'create directory in input folder with timestamp as the directory name.

    Dim destdir As String = [String].Format("\\ServerA\ITDept\files\{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss"))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destdir)

    'read directory and look for filenames that match pattern and have code elements from xml file

    Dim regElemName As New Regex("^code")
    Dim root = XElement.Load(xmlfile)
    Dim codeElements = root.Element("ApplicationSettings").Elements().Where(Function(xe) regElemName.IsMatch(xe.Name.LocalName)).Select(Function(xe) xe.Value)
    Dim codes = String.Join("|", codeElements.ToArray())
    Dim regFileName As New Regex(String.Format("^\d+\-(?<Year>(19|20)[0-9][0-9])(?<Month>0[1-9]|12|11|10)(?<Day>[12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01])\-{0}$", codes))
    Dim files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(Function(path) regFileName.IsMatch(IO.Path.GetFileName(path)))

    For Each file As String In files
        System.IO.File.Move(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(destdir, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)))
    Next

    'Define random numbers

    Dim randomclass As New System.Random()
    Dim randomnumber As Integer

    'create txt file from destdir of all files for output.

    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    For Each rfiles As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(destdir)

        randomnumber = randomclass.Next(10000, 99999)

        Dim formattedDate As String = GetFormattedDateFromFileName(rfiles)

        str = str & rfiles & "|" & System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rfiles).Split("-")(0).Trim & "|" & "_" & "||" & "docgroup_value" & "|" & "doctype_value" & "|" & "docsubtype_value" & "|" & "swfoi" & randomnumber & "|" & formattedDate & "|" & Environment.NewLine

    Next

    Dim outputname As String = [String].Format("\\ServerA\ITDept\Index\swfoi{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss"))
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputname, str)

End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone help me complete this code?

Kind Regards,
A

Comment: Shouldn't `docgroup`, `doctype`, and `docsubtype` be children of `code`, not siblings?

Comment: @Tim Don't know. As I said before I am quite new to VB.net.

Comment: You're quite close to what you want to do - there's a couple of things I'd recommend changing (in addition to the XML format), and you're missing the part where you get the docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values (which I think is what you're really asking for help on).  If someone else doesn't get to this first, I'll try and come back this evening (west coast time) and give some suggestions.

Comment: @Tim Yep that's exactly what I'm asking help on "getting the docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values". Apologies if I am all over the place in my explaintion, just wasn't sure how to explain it. Appreciate your help or anyone elses who wants to go at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much on the right track - there are a couple of things I would suggest doing to finish your code up.  My suggestions are one way - there are undoubtedly others, as most things in programming can be done a number of ways.  Sometimes one way is better or more preferable than another, sometimes it just boils down to personal preference or a given team's coding standards.

First, I'd modify your XML file so that the docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values are children of the code element.  XML is hierarchical in nature (think of folders and files in Windows Explorer), and organizing the XML that way makes it easier to search.

So:

```
<Settings>
  <ApplicationSettings>
    <code id="FTO">
      <docgroup>Operations</docgroup>
      <doctype>Funds Transfer</doctype>
      <docsubtype>Out</docsubtype>
    </code>
    <code id="FTI">
      <docgroup>null</docgroup>
      <doctype>null</doctype>
      <docsubtype>null</docsubtype>
    </code>
    <code id="ACL">
      <docgroup>Documentation</docgroup>
      <doctype>Client Documentation</doctype>
      <docsubtype>Termination</docsubtype>
    </code>
    <code id="TBA">
      <docgroup>Operations</docgroup>
      <doctype>Funds Transfer Credit</doctype>
      <docsubtype>Reversed</docsubtype>
    </code>
  </ApplicationSettings>
</Settings>
```

Note that I moved the value for the `<code>` element to an attribute, as you can't mix text and children elements in XML for a given element (at least not that I'm aware of).

Next, I would parse the XML once, and use a Dictionary to hold the data, with the code as the key and a `List<string>` holding the docgroup, doctype and docsubtype values.

Also, I wouldn't use a regular expression to find a match in the XML - regular expressions are great for pattern matching (like looking for file names that fit a certain pattern), but are overkill in a lot of other scenarios.  So as an aside, another way to do your search for the proper codes would be this:

```
Dim codeElements = root.Descendants("code").Select(Function(xe) xe.Attribute("id").Value).ToArray()
```

The above code is basically saying give me all the nodes named "code" that are children of the root element and put the value of their "id" attribute in an array.

To build a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` from the XML (using the XML format I posted), you would do this:

```
Dim docTypes As Dictionary(Of String, String) = root.Descendants("code") _
                .ToDictionary(Function(xe) xe.Attribute("id").Value,
                              Function(xe) New List(Of String)(New String() _
                 { xe.Element("docgroup").Value, _
                 xe.Element("doctype").Value, _
                 xe.Element("docsubtype").Value }))
```

(You may have to play with the formatting a bit in the IDE - I broke it up for readability here).  This gives you a dictionary where the key is the code and the child elements are a list (with element 0 = docgroup, 1 = doctype and 2 = docsubtype).

You could than get the proper docgroup, doctype and docsubtype from the dictionary.

Putting it all together you'd have something like this:

First, replace these lines of code:

```
Dim regElemName As New Regex("^code")
Dim root = XElement.Load(xmlfile)
Dim codeElements = root.Element("ApplicationSettings").Elements().Where(Function(xe) regElemName.IsMatch(xe.Name.LocalName)).Select(Function(xe) xe.Value)
Dim codes = String.Join("|", codeElements.ToArray())
```

With this (explanation following):

```
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(xmlfile)
Dim CodeInfo As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = _
             xml.Descendants("code") _
             .ToDictionary(Function(xe) xe.Attribute("id").Value, _
                           Function(xe) New List(Of String)(New String() _
                           { xe.Element("docgroup").Value, _
                             xe.Element("doctype").Value, _
                             xe.Element("docsubtype").Value }))
Dim codes As String = String.Join("|", CodeInfo.Keys)
```

In a nutshell, the above code loads the XML file, parses it into a dictionary (with code as the key and a `List(Of String)` of the doc type info as the value.  Then the string for the codes used in the regex is created by calling `String.Join` on the `Keys` property of the dictionary.

Now when you go to write the information to the text file, you can get the proper values based on the code.  A couple of changes here as well.

First, I'd split the filename on `-` before creating the line for the file, as you'll need it to get the proper code.  Assuming that all your codes are three characters, you'll only need the first three characters of the third element in the split array.  You'll pass that value in as the key to get the proper doc type values for the code.

Second, I'd suggest using `StringBuilder` (you may need to add `Imports System.Text` to your program).  The reason for this is that string concatenation can get expensive (imagine if you had 1,000 files to go through).  Strings are immutable - meaning they can't be changed.  So when you have something like:

```
Dim str1 As String = "Hello"

str1 = str1 & " World"
```

You might think that " World" was added to str1.  In reality, a new string was created that had str1 with " World" added - so imagine what happens if you do that 1,000 times.  For readability in the following example, I've also used `String.Format`.

Replace this line:

```
Dim str As String = String.Empty
```

with the following:

```
Dim str As New StringBuilder()
Dim fileNameParts As String()
Dim docCode As String = String.Empty
Dim str As New StringBuilder()
```

Then I'd replace your `str = str & rfiles &...` line with the following code:

```
fileNameParts = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rfiles).Split("-")
docCode = fileNameParts(2).Substring(0, 3)
str.Append(String.Format("{0}|{1}|_|||{2}|{3}|{4}|swfoi{5}|{6}|{7}", _
           rfiles, _
           fileNameParts(0).Trim(), _
           CodeInfo(docCode)(0),
           CodeInfo(docCode)(1),
           CodeInfo(docCode)(2),
           randomnumber,
           formattedDate,
           Environment.NewLine))
```

The code above does the following:

First, it splits the current filename on "-".  It then takes the first three characters of the third element from the split (the document code) and assigns it to the `docCode` variable.

Then it adds a line to the `StringBuilder str`, using `String.Format`.  Notice how I get the document type info from the dictionary, using the code as the key and referencing the correct element of the `List(Of String)` value associated with that key:

```
CodeInfo(docCode)(0) returns the `docgroup` value for that code.
```

Finally, you will need to call `ToString()` on `str` to output the contents of the `StringBuilder`:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputname, str.ToString())
```

A couple of other small points to consider:

I would double check your regex for the filename pattern match, as the days part seems a little off.  Also, you can get rid of the named groups (e.g., `?<Year>`) unless you have a use for them later.

Finally, I'd choose a different variable name for the XML File than `root`.  In LINQ to XML, `Root` is a property that returns the root of the XML - it could be confusing to other developers if they don't look closely enough at the code.

Finally, you'll want to include error handling (either defensive coding and/or Try-Catch blocks) in case a given key isn't found, or an element in the XML file is missing, etc.

I hope this helps - if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. Especially for the explainations of each. Other experts would just write the needed code and no explaination, so I very much appreciate your time in explaining this as well. One question for right now though what does the _ (underscore) mean at the end of some lines of your code?

Comment: @Andrea - You're welcome.  I'm hardly an expert, but I prefer to understand the *why* of the code, not just the how.  The underscore character is a line continuation character in VB.NET - it allows you to break a single statement (line) of code over several lines in the editor in VS.  Happy coding!

Comment: Tim I need some help. I've been trying to figure this out on my own for the last week but havent been able to. I think you did a typo for getting the correct doc type from the dictionary. I've changed these lines "DocInfo(code)(0)..." to "CodeInfo("code")(0)..." as docinfo is not declared so i figured you meant the dictionary variable. But when i run, the error im getting is "An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. 
Additional information: The given key was not...

Comment: ...present in the dictionary. I understand this means that it can't find the value in the xml file. BUt dont understand why. I've tried making the dictionary more specific by modifying this "xml.Descendants("code")" to this "xml.Element("ApplicationSettings").Elements("code")" but still i am getting the same error. 
Do you mind looking at this again and telling me what is wrong?

Comment: @Andrea - Yes, that was a typo.  It should be CodeInfo (I've edited the answer to fix this).   In your current code, are you using `CodeInfo("code")(0)` (note the " around code)?  If you are, that's probably the reason you're getting the error.  code is the name of the variable that holds the actual code value, so you'll want to use it without the " - `CodeInfo(code)(0)`.

Comment: Morning Tim, I understand the concept that the (code) is the variable that holds the actual value, but the reason i put the quotation marks around it was that Visual Studio is saying that the 'code' value is not declared. So this is why i thought quotations around the code like this CodeInfo("code")(0), would fix it. Apparently it doesnt though. See what I mean?

Comment: @Andrea - I think I found it - `code` should be `docCode`; if you look at the code sample, `docCode` is assigned the 3 digit document code from the filename.  I'll edit my post to fix the typo.

Comment: Thanks Tim that was it. I have another question though. This line "docCode = fileNameParts(3).Substring(0, 3)", Ive change the fileNameParts(3) to a fileNameParts(2) cause the array should start from 0 to 2 for all 3 parts correct? When i write this to console though only FTO FT is outputting and I get this error: An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary. Would you know why it would not complete the array and throw an error?

Comment: @Andrea...wow, I posted code full or errors.  Sorry about that (I'll edit it shortly).   I'm not sure I understand the last part though - if the filename is "12345-20130610-FTO Reviewed and scanned.pdf", then splitting on "-" should result in an array of 3 elements, and array[2].Substring(0, 3) should give "FTO" as the result. Are you saying you're seeing "FTO FT"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, ive been out of town. Yes, that is correct. The output to the console is saying "A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll FTO FT An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: @Andrea - It's hard to say without seeing the code.  If you'd like, you can e-mail it to me (my e-mail address is in my profile) and I'll take a look at over the next couple of days.

Comment: That's very kind of you. I will send you the code today some time. Thx

Comment: Im recieving a mailer-daemon when trying to send to your profiles gmail account (bentwingedbird). Do you have another I can send this to?

Comment: @Andrea - it might be because there's code.  Can you post the code to something like pastebin or some other repository and I can pull it from there?

Comment: @Andrea - can you post the XML file you're using as well?  At a glance the code should work.  Thanks.